# How to plan a model relation for collage admission app in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want a basic student **Registration & Login** facility.

After login, the student should be directed to a **Registration Form** which contains forms for student contact details and student marks.

### **Student contact details form contains**

```
student contact form
    first name
    last name
    address
    mobile no
    gender
    fathers name
    fathers occupation
    mothers name.
```

### Student marks list contains

```
**registration form**
    .
    |-- Board of examination
    |   `-- Branches(ex:science,:humanities)
    |       `--science[when i choose science]
               `--science subject1
               `--science subject2
               `--common paper for sciecnce and humanities
    |       `--humanities[when is choose humanities]
               `--humanities subject1
               `--humanities subject2
               `--common paper for sciecnce and humanities
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please make an effort to make your question more readable by checking spelling, grammar and general readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about how the data relates to each other. The tree that you've started with Examination Board gives some clues. A user will have more than one subject and more than one mark. How a are users and subjects and marks associated? One possibility

```
class User
  has_many :subject_marks
  has_many :subjects, through: subject_marks
end

class Subject
  belongs_to :branch
  has_many :subject_marks
  has_many :users, through: subject_marks
end

class SubjectMark
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :subject
end

class Branch
  has_many :subjects
  belongs_to :examination_board
end

class ExaminationBoard
  has_many :branches
end
```

Comment: i want **student** to register collage admission form ,so  do we  have to use **Registration** model here??

**Registration**     model contains Student contacts and Student Mark

Comment: If you intend to track Registrations in any way, then yes. A Registration would belong_to a Student. I would keep contact details on the Student model and student mark details on the SubjectMark model.